# C++ Compiler Seemingly Skipping Lines of Code, Skipping Straight to Object Class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm making a program that collects some data about netflix shows (from keyboard input) using object classes. However, when i run it, the program immedatly starts requesting cins from within the series class, skipping the first cin that requests the list name, and seemingly the while loop as well, as none of the couts i typed in as a debugging method show up in the terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Series.h"
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    // Variables
    const int MAX_SERIES = 20; // Set max size for series array, prevent misclicks or other mistakes.
    Series mySeries[MAX_SERIES]; // Series array
    string listName; // Name of the list
    
    // Input
    cout << "gets list name" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, listName); // Gets the name of the series list
    cout << "the listname is" << listName << endl;

    // Process
    int currentSeries = 0; // Array position. Start in 0

    // While true, since no conditions are available. Capture series details until a blank input is received for the series name
    while (true) 
    {
        cout << "starts process" << endl;
        mySeries[currentSeries] = Series(); // CODE SKIPS STRAIGHT TO THIS LINE (apparently)

        // Checks if getName has a blank space to terminate the code
        if (mySeries[currentSeries].getName().empty()) 
        {
            break;   // While loop breaks if series name is blank
        }
        currentSeries++;

        // Make sure the array size is smaller than 20
        if (currentSeries >= MAX_SERIES) 
        {
            break; // While loop breaks if current series is bigger than the array size
        }
    }


    // Output

    // Display the list name and series details
    cout << listName << endl;

    for (int seriesNumber = 0; seriesNumber < currentSeries; ++seriesNumber) 
    {
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getName() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getGenre() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getSeasons() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getEpisodes() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getYear() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getMRating() << endl;
        cout << mySeries[seriesNumber].getActors() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the Series.h code, for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Actor.h"
using namespace std;

class Series 
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        Series();

        // Setter functions
        void setName();
        void setGenre();
        void setSeasons();
        void setEpisodes();
        void setYear();
        void setMRating();
        void setActors();

        // Getter functions
        string getName();
        string getGenre();
        int getSeasons();
        int getEpisodes();
        int getYear();
        string getMRating();
        string getActors();

    private:
        string name;
        string genre;
        int seasons;
        int episodes;
        int year;
        string mRating;
        string actors; 
};
// Constructor
Series::Series() 
{
    setName();
    setGenre();
    setSeasons();
    setEpisodes();
    setYear();
    setMRating();
    setActors();
}

// Setter functions
void Series::setName() 
{
    cout << "gets series name" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    
}
void Series::setGenre() 
{
    cout << "gets series genre" << endl;
    getline(cin, genre);
}
void Series::setSeasons() 
{
    cout << "gets series seasons" << endl;
    cin >> seasons;
}
void Series::setEpisodes() 
{
    cout << "gets series episodes" << endl;
    cin >> episodes;
}
void Series::setYear() 
{
    cout << "gets series release year" << endl;
    cin >> year;
}
void Series::setMRating() 
{
    cout << "gets series maturity rating" << endl;
    getline(cin, mRating);
}
void Series::setActors()
{
    cout << "gets series actors" << endl;
    getline(cin, actors);
}

// Getter functions
string Series::getName()
{
    return name;
}
string Series::getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}
int Series::getSeasons()
{
    return seasons;
}
int Series::getEpisodes()
{
    return episodes;
}
int Series::getYear()
{
    return year;
}
string Series::getMRating()
{
    return mRating;
}
string Series::getActors() 
{
    return actors;
}
```

This is what the output looks like (apologies for the code format, its a terminal window display):

```
gets series name
>> my series
gets series genre
>> action
gets series seasons
>> 3
>> 24
>> 2014
>> TV-MA
gets series name
>> my series
gets series genre
>> action
gets series seasons
>> 4
>> 34
>> 2005
>> tv-ma
gets series name
```

it does not request the list name, and from there on it just loops infinitely

thought it was a problem with the cins, but it apparently is not. im stuck

Comment: The constructor of your class calls the functions that ask for input. In `main()`, the line `Series mySeries[MAX_SERIES];` invokes the constructor 20 times, once for each item in the array.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173)

Comment: It's a very bad idea to put side effects in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the constructor gets called 20 times when you declare the array. Instead you can use `std::vector`.

1. Remove the constructor from Series.
2. Add a free function above `int main()`:

   ```
   Series create_new_series()
   {
       Series new_series;
       new_series.setName();
       new_series.setGenre();
       new_series.setSeasons();
       new_series.setEpisodes();
       new_series.setYear();
       new_series.setMRating();
       new_series.setActors();
       return new_series;
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, you can also create a public static method in Series.
3. Replace `Series mySeries[MAX_SERIES];` with `std::vector<Series> mySeries;`
4. Replace `mySeries[currentSeries] = Series();` with `mySeries.push_back(create_new_series());`